# Reload DataTable on Every Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

All I am trying to do is that I want to refresh my DataTable when the page is relaoded/refreshed. Right now on refreshing the page it retains its data. My application is using ASP.Net MVC tech. 
Here is my Data Table and relevant functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //debugger;
    var table = $('#user_session_center_grid').DataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "colReorder": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "ajax": {
            cache: false,
            url: "@Url.Action("GetUserSessionHistory", "LoggedIn")",
            type: 'POST',
            data: function (data) {
                data.SortBy = 'Month';
                data.FromDate = "";
                data.ToDate = "";
                data.userSearch = $('#userSearch').val();
                if (event) {
                    var objDtFilter = event.target;
                    if ($(objDtFilter).hasClass('dtFilter')) {
                        data.FromDate = event.target.getAttribute('fromdt');
                        data.ToDate = event.target.getAttribute('todt');
                    }
                    if ($(objDtFilter).hasClass('dtSort'))
                        data.SortBy = event.target.getAttribute('sort');
                    if ($(objDtFilter).hasClass('UserTypeFilter'))
                        data.value1 = event.target.getAttribute('value');
                    console.log(data.value1);
                }
            },
        },
        "language": {
            oPaginate: {
                sNext: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                sFirst: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                sLast: '<i class="fa fa fa-chevron-left"></i>'
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                data: null,
                class: "userName",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<div>" + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName + "</div></td>";
                }
            },

            {
                data: null,
                class: "startDate",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var parsedDate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.StartTime), ToJavaScriptDate);
                    return "<div>" + parsedDate + "</div></td>";
                }
            },

                //{ 'data': 'User_ID' },
                //{ 'data': 'FirstName' },
                //{ 'data': 'LastName' },
                //{ 'data': 'StartTime' },
        ],
    });

   table.on('draw', function () {
       var widthofPagination = $('.dataTables_paginate.paging_simple_numbers').width() + 25;
       $('#user_session_center_grid_info').css({ width: 'calc(100% - ' + widthofPagination + 'px)' });

   });
    $("#date_filter_ul.dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        //debugger;
        $('#date_filter_ul').removeClass('show');
        $(this).closest('#CategoryFilter').find('.csp-select > span').text("Duration:" + $(this).text());
        $('#user_session_center_grid').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    });

    $("#user_session_center_status_ul.dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        $('#user_session_center_status_ul').removeClass('open');
        $(this).closest('#StatusFilter').find('.csp-select > span').text($(this).text());
        $('#user_session_center_grid').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

Here are my controller functions:

```
public ActionResult UserSessionCenter()
    {
            if (Session["selectedCustomer"] == null)
            {
                Session["selectedCustomer"] = 9;
            }

            int customerId = (int)Session["selectedCustomer"];
            var model = new UserSessionHistory();
            var daccess = new ApplicationCommon.Ado.SqlDataAccess();
            var customerNamesDt = daccess.GetUserNames(customerId);
            var customerList = new List<UserSessionData>();
            for (var i = 0; i < customerNamesDt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var userinfo = new UserSessionData();
                userinfo.CustomerId = customerNamesDt?.Rows[i]["Customer_Id"].ToString() ?? "";
                userinfo.CustomerName = customerNamesDt?.Rows[i]["Customer_Name"].ToString() ?? "";
                userinfo.UserId = customerNamesDt?.Rows[i]["User_ID"].ToString() ?? "";
                userinfo.UserName = customerNamesDt?.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString() ?? "";
                customerList.Add(userinfo);
            }
            model.UserInfoList = customerList;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public JsonResult GetUserSessionHistory()
    {
        var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
        var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
        var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
        if (Request["value1"] != null)
            Session["userId"] = Request["value1"]; 
        int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
        try
        {
            var UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"]);
            var filterModel = new FilterSessionHistoryModel();
            filterModel.UserID = UserID;
            filterModel.Skip = int.Parse(start);
            filterModel.Take = int.Parse(length);
            var fromDate = Request["FromDate"];
            var toDate = Request["ToDate"];
            filterModel.userSearch = Request["userSearch"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
            {
                filterModel.DateFrom = fromDate;
                filterModel.DateTo = toDate;
            }
            UserService userService = new UserService();
            List<ADM_User_Session_History_Result> SessionList = userService.ADM_User_Session_History(filterModel);
            int? numberOfRecords = 0;
            if(SessionList.Count>0) {
                numberOfRecords=SessionList[0].NumberOfRecords;
            }
            return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = (int)numberOfRecords, recordsTotal = (int)numberOfRecords, data = SessionList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomLogging.LogMessage(ex.Message + "/r/n" + ex.Source + "/r/n" + ex.StackTrace, LogType.Error);
            return this.GetJSONObject(false, ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The hierarchy is like this.
1. The Admin user can use any customer
2. One customer can have many users
3. The table shows the time of log in of the user selected.

The problem is that the list through which the Admin can change the Customer is in the top nav present in _Layout.cshtml where as this data table is in another view. The data changes fine while cahanging the user but I need it to reload or get empty when the customer is changed.

Comment: How are you binding data to your datatable? Show your code

Comment: It should refresh the datatable-- if you didn't use static content.

Comment: Hello @Mark. My code is kind of all over the place and hence will be hard to paste here. I am actually binding my data using entity framework which creates a complex type of a SP.

Comment: @TahaAzhar at least post the datatable script and the controller action

Comment: @Jerdine I have posted the code,

Answer (score 0):

old browsers like 'explorer' keep caching the info from a first ajax call, 
you can try to set the cash flag to false and the table will be updated each time

```
function ReLoadTable() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: 'Your URL',
            type: 'POST',
```

in controller put this attribute

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

finally in your Global.asax file add this function

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
    }
```

Comment: Hey Erwin. Thanks for the reply but it does not seem to fix the problem I am having.

Comment: im sur its a caching problem, try to decorate your controller with  [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

Comment: Still not working. I think the data from the DB in the datatable just remains there on even after reloading the view.

Comment: if the data does not change in you DB how do you expect to be changed in your view ?

Comment: My functionality is that the admin user can switch and see the data of every user in the application. When the data of one user is displayed in the data table, upon selecting another user the data of the previous user remains in the table. I want the Data Table to show there is no data every time a new user is selected. The page is refreshed upon changing the user as well.

Comment: do you reload your table at ajax success ? 'YourTable.Ajax.reload()'

Comment: I reload the data table on change of the user

Comment: post you jquery script